# My Python/WebKit code is skipping over tags

Tags: python-3.x, webkit, pyqt5

I have an issue with this "ghost" data. I'm assuming it is dynamic java but I'm not a whiz and I can't seem to figure out why the `<tbody>` tag is being left out. I've tried a few different ways and no matter what I run that tag and portion of the output is always skipped over. Below is a picture of the inspect window of the website [Website Inspect Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97DCR.png)
Here is the code:

```
    import sys  
    from PyQt5.QtGui import *  
    from PyQt5.QtCore import *  
    from PyQt5.QtWebKit import *  
    from lxml import html 
    from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import QWebPage
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

    class Render(QWebPage):  
      def __init__(self, url):  
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)  
        QWebPage.__init__(self)  
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)  
        self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))  
        self.app.exec_()  

      def _loadFinished(self, result):  
        self.frame = self.mainFrame()  
        self.app.quit()

    url = 
('https://cib.societegenerale.com/fileadmin/indices_feeds/ti_screen/index.html')  
    #This does the magic.Loads everything
    r = Render(url)  
    #result is a QString.
    result = r.frame.toHtml()
    print(result)
```

Here is the output:

```
    <div id="watchlist" align="right">
            <table id="watchlistTable" class="hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <thead>
                            <tr>
                                    <td colspan="8" class="heading" align="left">Market Signal Watch List</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                    <th></th>
                                    <th>Market</th>
                                    <th>Current Position</th>
                                    <th>Yesterday's Close</th>
                                    <th>20 Day Moving Average</th>
                                    <th>120 Day Moving Average</th>
                                    <th>Reversal Price</th>
                                    <th>Reversal Price Move</th>
                            </tr>
                    </thead>
            </table>
            <div class="source">source: SG Prime Services &amp; Bloomberg</div>
    </div>
```

As you can see the `<tbody>`tag is nowhere to be found. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: It is not a duplicate post. If you examine the screenshot I included in the first paragraph, you can see that there is a tag between </thead> and </table> that is in the source code but not in the output.

Comment: @JoshPilson. If you use "view source" in a browser, you will see that the original html does not contain any tbody tags (or at least, that's what firefox shows). So the missing html must be inserted dynamically after the page has loaded. If you use a single-shot timer and print the html after a 1-2 second delay, the missing parts will show up.